# Would analytics.js be affected by Google Analytics mobile apps reporting and the legacy Google Analytics Services SDK sunset

Tags: google-analytics

We have a web application that uses analytics.js of google analytics, and we received an email from google analytics team stating that:

> This is a reminder that your Google Analytics account(s) XYZ and their
>   properties listed below use the older style of Google Analytics mobile
>   apps reporting and the legacy Google Analytics Services SDK, which
>   will be sunset starting this October when we will stop collecting data
>   for your property 
>   ....
>
> What will happen to my Google Analytics properties listed above?
>
> • Starting in October, we will begin to decommission properties that
>   were identified at the time of our first notice as receiving data
>   exclusively from the Google Analytics Services SDK.
>
> • Data collection and processing for such properties will stop October
>   31, 2019.
>
> • Reporting access through our UI and API access will remain available
>   for these properties’ historical data until January 31, 2020.
>
> • After our service is fully turned down in February 2020, these
>   legacy properties will no longer be accessible via our Google
>   Analytics UI or API, and their data will be removed from Google
>   Analytics servers. You will receive additional notification as these
>   deadlines approach.

My questions are:

1. would analytics.js be affected by Google Analytics mobile apps
   reporting and the legacy Google Analytics Services SDK sunset?
2. If I create a new Apps property or (Apps and web) property today, will it be decommission on October?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. No, analytics.js won't be affected. Analytics.js is the library you're using to send data to GA.
2. If you create a new apps property, the wizard would walk you through and create a Firebase property, which is what it is suggested migration path in the sunset. There is also the new "Web and App" property type that would allow you to track app and web users in the same property.

Comment: I created a Web + Apps property but it seems like there is no way to send events to it through analytics.js, should I migrate to gtag.js